# Owner Permissions Set Too Restrictively

Tags: macos, unix, permissions

EDIT: was able to fix this by logging in with another account in the same group, and accessing it that way.  It only worked because I was lucky enough to have that other account in the same group though. I'd still like to know if there's another way around this issue.

hmm...

i meant to do

```
> chmod 755 <directory>
```

but I typed

```
> chmod 75 <directory>
```

which results in

```
> d---rwxr-x   5 justin        512 Oct 24 19:35 gallery
```

I own the directory, but can't access it.

I don't have root.

What to do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've managed to give the group owner full access (assuming there is one; your `ls` output doesn't indicate one).  If there is a group owner, say, group `foo`, you could log in to the group with `newgrp`:

```
$ newgrp foo
```

This might allow you to issue the corrective `chmod 755 <directory>`.

You could also try to recursively `chmod` the parent directory, if you own it.  Be careful to record permissions on other subdirectories and files so you can restore them properly later.

Barring either of those solutions, you'll have to contact the system administrator to fix it for you.  Some breakages just require root to fix.

Comment: was able to fix this by logging in with another account (just happen to have 2 accounts) with membership in the same group as the directory, and issuing the chmod that way, restoring owner permissions.  It's weird how that worked out, but it makes sense; permissions are matched from left to right, and the first match "wins".  Thanks all for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do:

```
chmod 755 <directory>
```

If that does not work, running it as root will work:

```
sudo chmod 755 <directory>
```

Comment: Neither works, unfortunately, because I have no access to the directory, and don't have root access. But I own the directory.  It's crazy.

Comment: I tried these on my system (Linux, GNU coreutils), and they worked. Perhaps it would be good to specify exactly what unix you're using.

Comment: Mac OS X, actually. I think it was an issue with groups. Once I chgrp'd it, I was able to remove it.  Thanks for the quick replies.

Comment: you should set that as an answer then.

Comment: Definitely add chgrp as an answer!  Maybe my answer will work for other people.  I'm sorry it didn't work for you, but I'm very happy you seem to have solved your problem.